# How to convert this deferred style promise to ES6 style promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deferred, es6-promise

Refer to *Rookie mistake #4: using "deferred"* in [Nolan Lawson](https://twitter.com/nolanlawson)'s article: [We have a problem with promises](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) (btw a great post!), I try not to use deferred style promises anymore. Recently I've encountered a practical example that I can't figure out how to NOT code this in deferred way, so I need some advices.

Here is the example, an angular factory:

```js
function ConfirmModal($q, $modal) {
    return {
        showModal: function _showModal(options) {
            var _modal = $modal(options)
            var deferred = $q.defer()

            _modalScope.confirm = function(result) {
                deferred.resolve(result)
                _modal.hide()
            }

            _modalScope.cancel = function(reason) {
                deferred.reject(reason)
                _modal.hide()
            }

            return deferred.promise
        }
    }
}
```

I hide some unrelated details(eg. implementation of `_modalScope`), the core idea is: `$modal` provide a ui widget which contains two button: **Confirm** and **Cancel**. When **Confirm** is been clicked, call `_modalScope.confirm` and resolve the deferred promise, otherwise reject the deferred promise by calling `_modalScope.cancel` when **Cancel** is been clicked.

I tried to rewrite by using `return $q(function(resolve, reject) { ... })`, but I really don't know how/when to call `resolve` and `reject` in this constructor, because the real logic is in the `_modalScope.confirm/cancel` method. I'm struggled with this problem for days, really hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: In fact, you are not using the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) here, because `$modal` is not a promise api already. Deferreds are totally fine for promisifying things!

Comment: @Bergi oh, fairly point, I didn't realize that, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming the code in your questions is functional and `_modalScope` is accessible from the `_showModal()` function, then the code below should answer your question:

```
function ConfirmModal($q, $modal) {
    return {
        showModal: function _showModal(options) {
            return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                var _modal = $modal(options)

                _modalScope.confirm = function(result) {
                    resolve(result)
                    _modal.hide()
                }

                _modalScope.cancel = function(reason) {
                    reject(reason)
                    _modal.hide()
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this before and I thought it not works, and I tried it again after read your answer, it actually works!

I thought it not works because angular throws an error, but I didn't read it carefully, turns out the error is not related to this modification, my bad.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Won't work with Angular 1.2.  Unsure about Angular 1.3.  Seems to work with Angular 1.4 and 1.5.